# How to get backup with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When I want to take a back up I confront to this command

mongodump -d databasename -u admin -p -o /home

```
I encounter an error Errmsg: "auth faild",code:18}
```

But with this user and pass I can connect to database
But while I would prefer to disconnect authentication
I will Get backup

Thanks

Comment: You should concider this - http://www.arvinep.com/2016/02/mongodb-auth-failed.html

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that `mongodump` couldn't authenticate against the `mongod`. There are a few possible causes. Looking at [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-password) we can see the following note about the `-p` option.

> Changed in version 3.0.0: If you do not specify an argument for
>   --password, mongodump returns an error.
>
> Changed in version 3.0.2: If you wish mongodump to prompt the user for
>   the password, pass the --username option without --password or specify
>   an empty string as the --password value, as in --password "" .

In the example command you provided, there is just a `-p` which means it is expecting a password.

Additionally, the `--authenticationDatabase` option is missing. Looking at the docs for `mongodump`:

> Specifies the database in which the user is created. See
>   Authentication Database.
>
> If you do not specify an authentication database, mongodump assumes
>   that the database specified to export holds the user’s credentials.
>
> If you do not specify an authentication database or a database to
>   export, mongodump assumes the admin database holds the user’s
>   credentials.

Since the `-d` parameter is specified, `mongodump` will try to authenticate against that database. It is more likely that the user exists in the `admin` database.

Taking all of this into account, please try the following command:

```
mongodump -d <databasename> -u <user> --authenticationDatabase admin -o /home
```

This command will prompt you for a password via `stdin`. If you want to specify the password on the command line, the command changes to

```
mongodump -d <databasename> -u <user> --authenticationDatabase admin -p <password> -o /home
```

Please replace `<databasename>`, `<user>`, and `<password>` with the appropriate values for your environment.

Comment: thank you 
The version used is 2.6 Authentication error was received

Comment: both `mongodump` and `mongod` are 2.6?

Comment: Yes . Mongodump version is 2.6.10

Comment: FWIW, MongoDB 2.6 was EOL October 2016. That being said, despite being 2.6, nothing changes. The problem is still an incorrect username/password/database. How do you connect with the Mongo Shell or application? Are the users stored in Admin or in a different database?